# Cannot add new controls when creating a composite user control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to broaden my knowledge of user controls or to be more specific, composite user controls.  Msdn has a walkthrough on the subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which although not in VB is easy enough to follow and get results.

What I had had in mind was to create a base user control comprised of a split panel, one half of which would be used to display dynamic help and the other half which could house whatever controls the new user control which would inherit from this required.  The problem that I am facing is that when I then create a new inherited control based upon my base control I cannot add new controls to the design surface.  If I don't have a split panel filling the entire design surface of the base control I can add new controls, but if I do I can't.

Either I am doing something wrong, or more likely failing to do something on the base control that I ought to do , or this can't be done which I find odd to believe.  I'm hoping someone can explain what it is I've missed.

This is being targeted at winforms with vb.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Did you make the split panel's modifier to `protected` or `protected internal` or `public`? That should do the trick.

By default it is `private` and so designer will prevent you from accessing it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.  always nice to learn something new and to be reminded how easy it is to be crassly stupid.